# If you have a filtration in a group does it induce a filtration in a quotient?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, filtrations

Let us assume that a group $G$ has a filtration $\{N_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$. Let $A$ be a normal subgroup of $G$.
I want to know if it is always $$\bigcap_{i\in \mathbb{N}}N_iA=A?$$

I have not been able to find a counterexample or nor a proof.
It seems to me that it should be true but I am not sure how to prove it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Let $G = \mathbb{Z}$ be the additive group of integers. Let $N_{i} = (1 + 2 i) \mathbb{Z}$, for $i$ ranging in the natural numbers. This is a filtration of $\mathbb{Z}$. But if you take $A = 2 \mathbb{Z}$, then $N_{i} + A = \mathbb{Z}$ for all $i$.

Comment: What about if $A\cap N_i\not=1$ for all $i$?

Comment: That's the case in this example.